# Sidebar menu with uitableview in swift for ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sidebar

I'm new into ios development. I'm trying to implement a small contact manager application. I'm following a tutorial from this link http://www.kaleidosblog.com/swift-side-menu-tutorial-how-to-create-a-custom-side-menu-in-ios and I followed many, but which didn't satisfy my requirements. What I'm trying to achieve is having a sidebar menu, and have a table view as my main view. Most of the examples showed how to use them with a normal view controller. A clear example is how BBM works on iphone, when you tap more or the sidebar button. From the provided link, is there anywhere to change the initial view to table view? I've tried but it wasn't successful. I'll appreciate any help, My application as to be submitted soon. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried SWReavealViewController(https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) or you need to implement it by yourself?
I have my own SideBar implementation, but unfortunatelly, my implementation is in Portuguese, cause I made it specially for one of my learners (https://github.com/dedeexe/DDXSideBar)

Comment: I will try it within a hour and let you know. thanks for your suggestion. I will give it a try, I started with swift, no clue in obj-c. tutorials I followed works with UIView, but I want to use a uitableview.

Comment: check this out http://youtu.be/8EFfPT3UeWs

Comment: thanks. I've already watched it, but my question how can I change the uiview to uitableviewcontroller ?

Comment: thanks found a custom one

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link for side bar menu using `UITablView`

http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

Comment: Thanks but i'm not willing to use any plugins